# Error: Invalid grouping factor specification, Subject

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to run a multilevel logistic regression model in R.

Here is my model:

```
modA <- glmer(Past_01 ~ Scene_01 + Speech_01 + (1| Subject), data = df2, 
        family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"),
        nAGQ = 10)
```

When I run it, I receive the following:

Error: Invalid grouping factor specification, Subject.

Can someone tell me (a) what does this error mean? And/or (b) what is the solution?

While I noticed that identical questions have been asked, I have not yet found an answer that adequately resolves the issue.

These are the steps I have taken so far, based on the suggestions from previous related threads.

1. I removed the NAs BEFORE I ran the model using na.rm
2. I removed NAs using na.action=na.omit.
3. I doubled checked the structure of Subject (the grouping variable in question) and it is a factor. Past, Scene, and Speech are Integers.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Here is a sample of my data as @NelsonGon requested.

Using dput:

```
dput(head(df2,50))
```

I received the following output:

```
structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Trial = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L), Spont = 
c(NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
Speech_01 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Scene_01 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), VisElem_01 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AudElem_01 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Past_01 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Pres_01 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), Fut_01 = 
c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA)), 
.Names = c("Subject", "Trial", "Spont", "Speech_01", "Scene_01", 
"VisElem_01", "AudElem_01", "Past_01", "Pres_01", "Fut_01"), 
row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the structure of my data using str(df2).

```
'data.frame':   28800 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Subject   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Trial     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ Spont     : int  NA NA 3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Speech_01 : int  NA NA NA NA 0 NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Scene_01  : int  NA NA NA 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ VisElem_01: int  NA NA NA 0 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ AudElem_01: int  NA NA NA NA 0 NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Past_01   : int  NA NA NA NA NA 0 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Pres_01   : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 NA NA NA ...
 $ Fut_01    : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 NA NA ...
```

**Datatypes**
Subject is the participant ID. Spont is a continuous variable. The other variables (Scene_01, Speech_01, VisElem_01, AudElem_01, Past_01, Pres_01, and Fut_01) are dummy coded and have values of 1's and 0's (for yes and no respectively). In the model, I edited the variables to match the actual variable names in the dataframe.

**Note**
The NAs were produced during a dummy coding step where I used the dyplr::spread function on an existing column (from the original dataset) to create new columns out of the unique values of that existing column. If you are familiar with the dyplr::spread function, you may have noticed that it spreads out the data and produces a bunch of NAs.

Comment: Could you add a sample of the data using `dput(df2)` or `dput(head(df2,n))` with n being the minimum number of rows required for the data to be reproducible. Also could you add `str(df2)`?

Comment: Update: Since posting this question, I was able to understand and fix the issue. Restructuring the data from long to wide format created a ton of NAs (from restructuring) which were mixing with the real NAs from the original dataset (i.e., real NAs came from participants not responding on some trials). I wasn't able to properly carry the real NAs over when I restructured the data back from wide to long format. Will post the solution when I have a chance. Thanks @ NelsonGon as your tip gave me a leg up in seeing the source of the issue